# Pandas dataframe aggregated sum while retaining column names?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have code to read the [social security names file](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/names.zip) into a dataframe:

```
import glob

path ='/mnt/bigdata/GenderClassification/SSA'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/yob????.txt")


list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0,names=["Name","Gender","Frequency"])
    list_.append(df)
    #print file_
    #print df.loc[0,:]
ssi = pd.concat(list_)
ssi
```

[image]

Which I then aggregate with the sum on the Frequency:

```
ssi_sum=ssi.groupby(['Name','Gender']).aggregate(np.sum)
```

But the result looses the column specification:

[image]

So this is no longer possible due to a key error:

```
ssi_sum['Name']
```

And I can't just rename the columns due to a "length mismatch":

```
ssi_sum.columns=['Name','Gender','Frequency']
```

How do i do the aggregation and retain the column names?

Comment: Just reset the index, `ssi_sum.reset_index(inplace=True)` or `ssi_sum = ssi.groupby(['Name','Gender']).aggregate(np.sum).reset_index()`

Comment: Yeah, that works.  Thanks.  Weird that it messes up the index in the first place.  Not really sure what exactly is happening.

Comment: When you perform a groupby, the keys become the new index, there is a param `index=True` which you could change to `False` but this won't work in your case because it doesn't make sense to `sum` string values so you need to call `reset_index` on the aggregation like AChampion has suggested

Comment: AChampion, please turn your and @EdChum's comments into an answer and I will accept it as answered.  Thanks!